# Axiom Of Union in ZFC And Its Weaker Counterpart

Tags: set-theory

The axiom of union states that:

$$\forall F \exists A \forall x (x\in A \iff\exists S(x\in S \wedge S\in F))$$

The weak axiom of union states that:

$$\forall F \exists A \forall x (\exists S(x\in S \land S\in F) \implies x\in A )$$

In this article of wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_union

it states that the weak version only produces the superset of the union of a set.

What else does the full version produce? And why use the weak version instead of the full one? Is the full one provable from the weak version?

Thank you.

Comment: Does it produce the following thing? Given some set with elements, I can make a set of sets out of its elements.

Comment: The weak one is equivalent to the full one modulo the comprehension schema

Answer (score 3):

Assuming it is clear to you what the intuitive union is (i.e., the naive one we just take for granted as existing in elementary non-axiomatic set theory), and for simplicity let us speak just of the union of two sets $A, B$, the weak axiom of union guarantees the existence of a set which contains $A\cup B$, while the strong axiom states the existence of $A\cup B$ directly. The weak axiom together with the axiom of specification yields the strong axiom simply by using the property $P(x)=x\in A \vee x \in B$.

In more detail, the weak axiom may yield any set as long as it contains the naive $A\cup B$, and you simply do not know which one. More precisely, it yields some set which contains all the element in $A$ as well as all the element in $B$, but may contain more. I do not think there is much significance to stating the axiom of union weakly or strongly, seeing the two are equivalent given specification. In the absence of specification there may be many models in which the weak axiom holds, but the strong one fails.

Comment: So the weak axiom yields some set which contains all the element in A as well as all the element in B, but may contain more. And the strong version yields exactly that set which contains all the element in A as well as all the element in B and no more.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have the axiom schema of comprehension you can equivalently replace the axioms of pairing, union set, power set (and probably infinity) with a weaker version.

The purpose of these axioms are to be able to construct sufficiently complex and large sets. If you replace them with weaker versions you can always use the axiom schema of comprehension to slim the guaranteed set down to the originally desired set.

Comment: Also Replacement has a weaker variant, but then it does not imply Separation.